# Iterating over weeks in date-fns

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, date-fns

I'm using the date-fns library to build a calendar, and I need to get the weeks for a month.

```
let start = startOfMonth(date)
let end = endOfMonth(date)
let firstWeek = getISOWeek(start)
let lastWeek = getISOWeek(end)

let weeks = []

for (let i = firstWeek; i < lastWeek + 1; i++) {
  weeks.push(i)
}

return weeks
```

This works well for most months, except for the month of December, where weeks is empty because firstWeek and lastWeek are "48" and "1" respectively.

I know I can fix this with a more complex loop, to check if each iteration is higher or lower than the previous, but I'm wondering if there's a more natural/simple way to achieve this using date-fns (or es6).

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to defer getting of the ISO week and iterate over the actual dates, instead of dealing with week index numbers.

```
let startOfCurrent = startOfMonth(date)
let startOfNext = addMonths(startOfCurrent, 1)

let weeks = []

for (let i = startOfCurrent; isBefore(i, startOfNext); i = addWeeks(i, 1)) {
  weeks.push(getISOWeek(i))
}

return weeks
```